# How to insert a new row for each data in django?

Tags: django

I have a multiselct data (using select2) - by which user can select multiple datas and do a post !

This is how i receive the post request:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['XNcF2x.......'], 'document_type': ['equivalent', 'level', 'passport']}>
```

So now, i need to insert new rows for each of "document_type", in other words if document_type has three datas then i need to make 3 new rows ! How to do that ?

I have read few things `bulk_create` or is there any efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for document in document_type:
    new_doc = Document(document_type=document)
    new_doc.save()
    print("New document type saved.")
```

This would save all 3 as separate entries in the database.